# Create a new pandas DataFrame from an existing one based on whether it's multiIndex appears in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I want to be able to take a large DataFrame which has a multiIndex and create two new ones based on whether or not the index appears in a list.

As an example, lets say I have a DataFrame which has a MultiIndex of `['Name', 'Surname']` and columns of different test results `['Score1', 'Score2']`.
Given a list of names I want to be able to create two new DataFrames, one containing entries whose names are in the list and one whose names are not.

```
In [1]:
data = {'Name':['Jake', 'Jack', 'June', 'Jane'], 
        'Surname': ['Scott', 'Smith', 'Saint', 'Smith'],
        'Score1':[85, 78, 95, 90],
        'Score2': [79, 91, 83, 68]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.set_index(['Name', 'Surname'])
Males = [['Jake', 'Scott'], ['Jack', 'Smith']]
df

Out [1]:
            Score1  Score2
Name    Surname     
Jake    Scott   85  79
Jack    Smith   78  91
June    Saint   95  83
Jane    Smith   90  68
```

Then if a row index is in the `Males` it will be put into `MalesDF` else it will be put into `FemalesDF`

```
In [2]:    MalesDF

Out [2]: 
             Score1 Score2
Name    Surname     
Jake    Scott   85  79
Jack    Smith   78  91
```

Obviously in this small example it might be simple enough to do with a for loop but in my actual case I have thousands of names and a list about a quarter of the size. So a for loop would be too inefficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use, [`index.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) to create a boolean mask, and filter the df to create the male and female df based on this boolean mask:

```
m = df.index.isin(Males)
df_males = df[m]
df_females = df[~m]
```

Result:

```
# df_males
              Score1  Score2
Name Surname                
Jake Scott        85      79
Jack Smith        78      91

# df_females
              Score1  Score2
Name Surname                
June Saint        95      83
Jane Smith        90      68
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I got a TypeError unhashaple type: 'list' at first but once I converted `Males` from a list of lists into a tuple of tuples it worked perfectly :)